# How do get provideTasks method of registerTaskProvider working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to get the new `registerTaskProvider` method in the VSCode Task API working within my extension, and I have been unable to make this work so far.

I have used the npm extension as a basis.  Here are the steps that I have followed:

1. Used yo to create a new extension
2. Updated package.json to include a new activationEvent `onCommand:workbench.action.tasks.runTask`
3. Updated package.json to include `configuration` and `taskDefinitions` sections in the `contributes` section
4. Added the following code to the [extension.ts](https://gist.github.com/gep13/836535f7ef3affddb80e784cbe674bc5) file

**NOTE:** I realise that the linked code won't actually provide any additional tasks, I am just using this code as a basis for testing.

Now, when I try to debug the extension, the `provideTasks` method is never invoked.  What am I missing?

Also, the only way to have the activate method called is when I invoke the `Hello World` command.  However, I might not have a command associated with the extension.  How can I force the activation of the extension?

Is there any additional documentation on how to get started with the `registerTaskProvider` API?

I have added a sample repository that has the [current work to date](https://github.com/gep13/vscode-task-sample).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that this was a case of PEBKAC.

After a Twitter discussion with Erich Gamma, he showed me that the `provideTasks` method is only consulted when you begin running a task.  As shown here:

https://twitter.com/ErichGamma/status/885823516293177346

I had assumed that the `provideTasks` method would be consulted on activation of the extension.