# Unable to add tasks from the provideTasks function

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

Following on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090999) I have another question about how to implement the `provideTasks` method of the `registerTaskProvider`.

Using the npm extension as an [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/npm/src/main.ts#L97) I have tried to implement a basic function, to simply return a single, hard-coded, task.  This would then be extended to actually parse a file, ready to add dynamic tasks.  However, I have been unable to get this to work.

The code that I am trying is:

```
    vscode.workspace.findFiles('**/*.cake').then((files) => {
        if (files.length === 0) {
            return emptyTasks;
        }

        try {
            const result: vscode.Task[] = [];
            result.push(new vscode.Task({type: 'cake', script: 'NuGet-Restore'} as CakeTaskDefinition, 'Nuget-Restore', 'cake', new vscode.ShellExecution('npm install'), []));

            console.log(result);
            return Promise.resolve(result);
        } catch (e) {
            return Promise.resolve(emptyTasks);
        }
    });
```

Even though I can see that result contains a Task, I don't see it populated in the Task drop down list.

Can anyone offer any help in why this is not working?

A repository with the current code can be found [here](https://github.com/gep13/vscode-task-sample).

**UPDATE**

I have just edited the above code to be the following:

```
    try {
        const result: vscode.Task[] = [];
        result.push(new vscode.Task({ type: 'cake', script: 'NuGet-Restore' } as CakeTaskDefinition, 'Nuget-Restore', 'cake', new vscode.ShellExecution('npm install'), []));

       console.log(result);
       return Promise.resolve(result);
    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.resolve(emptyTasks);
    }
```

By not including the initial `findFiles` function, it correctly populates the Task Menu with the single hard-coded Task.  Why is it that I can't do the return from within the findFiles method?  I now suspect that this is a TypeScript/JavaScript problem, rather than one with the `provideTasks` function, but I am still looking for some help on this.

What is the recommended approach for what I am trying to do?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` `findFiles` to ensure the tasks are actually returned from the task provider:

```ts
return vscode.workspace.findFiles('**/*.cake').then((files) => {
    ...
});
```

Using `"noImplicitReturns": true` in your `tsconfig.json`—or, even better, `"strict": true`—can help catch bugs like this